# set of sets in C++

Tags: c++11, set

How to create a set of sets in C++?

```
set<char> inner1;
set<char> inner2;
set< set<char> > outer;
set< set<char> >:: iterator new_it;
set<char>::iterator it;

for (int i = 65; i < 70; ++i)
    inner1.insert(i);

for (int i = 70; i < 80; ++i)
    inner2.insert(i);

outer.insert(inner1);
outer.insert(inner2);

for(new_it=outer.begin();new_it!=outer.end();new_it++)
{
   for(it=*(new_it);it!=(new_it);)
   {

   }
}
```

Comment: the problem is with your loop, it should be `for(it=new_it->begin();it!=new_it->end();++it)`.

Comment: and also, consider using `std::move` when you insert the set into another one. your current implementation is somewhat inefficient

Comment: @PiotrS.: You beat me to it. If you answer, I'll delete mine.

Comment: @Beta no problem, I didn't plan to post an answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't assign `new_it` to `it` in the inner loop. Do it this way:

```
for(it = new_it->begin(); it!=new_it->end(); ++it)
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit your solution? I am not getting it.

Comment: @SachinSingh: My solution is a commonplace iteration over a container. In what way is it unclear?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to create a set of sets, but getting various errors while declaring it. I am doing something like this `std::set<std::set<int>> temp_moves`, is it correct? i am not sure how to use your answer to fix the issues I am facing? `error: no matching function for call to ‘std::set<std::set<int> >::insert(int&)’`

Comment: @SachinSingh: Your declaration looks correct (although older compilers prefer "> >" to ">>"). I do not think that my answer can solve your problem, but if you reduce your code to a minimal complete example (the shortest program that produces the error) you can post a Question about it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47253499/declaring-set-of-sets-with-integer-in-c