# declaring set of sets with integer in c++

Tags: c++, set

I am working on a c++ program with a set of sets. Here is the declared set of sets.

```
std::set< std::set<int> > temp_moves;
```

I am getting the error below in this declaration, my question is that is my syntax correct? is it possible to create a set of sets in programs?

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::set<std::set<int> >::insert(int&)’
```

Updated Code

```
   std::set<int> next_moves;
   std::set<int> available_numbers;
   for (const auto available_number : available_numbers)
        temp_moves.insert(number);
        temp_moves.insert(available_number);
   next_moves.insert(temp_moves);
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to insert an integer into your set of sets, when you should be inserting a set instead. Posting a [mcve] would help us be sure this is the case.

Comment: yes the inner sets contain numbers, that why declared like this.

Comment: From the error message you're trying to insert an integer into the **outer** set, which doesn't make sense. Something like `temp_moves.insert(5)` isn't correct when `temp_moves` contains sets and not integers.

Comment: Please show the code that tries to insert values. Anyway, are you sure you want a *set* of sets and not, for example, a vector of sets?

Comment: Your declaration compiles fine for me

Comment: Error messages are usually accompanied with the line number where error was encountered. I bet that you posted wrong line (not one causing error) in this question.

Comment: You need to use braces after a `for` loop unless it only has one statement within it. And `temp_moves.insert(available_number)` is the problem line, for the reasons mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inserting an integral value `available_number` into a data structure `temp_moves` that expects a set...

Probably not the logic that you want to achieve, but the following will at least compile. Hope it helps somehow:

```
std::set<int> next_moves;
std::set<int> available_numbers;
for (const auto available_number : available_numbers) {
  next_moves.insert(available_number);
}
temp_moves.insert(next_moves);
```